# How to bulk update a MongoDB string array to replace space with a hyphen?

Tags: sql, mongodb

I have a collection called `companies` that has an array type named `categories`.

How can I replace spaces (' ') in all categories arrays with '-'?

I have to do this with cmd

this is actually what I'm trying to do

Update Companies Set Categories=Categories.replace(" ","-")

Comment: You have to loop through and update each document.

Comment: If you post your language and or some code you have been working on - it may get you quicker results too.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your data like below way

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e7f809623d919fb0fc776a5"),
    "categories" : [ 
        "mayur ", 
        " wadekar ", 
        " stackoverflow"
    ]
}
```

If you wanted to replace the first occurrence of space then use

```
db.companies.find({}).forEach(function(e,i) {
    var data = e.categories
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        e.categories[i] = e.categories[i].replace(" ","-");
    }
    db.companies.save(e);
});
```

If you wanted to replace all spaces then use

```
db.companies.find({}).forEach(function(e,i) {
    var data = e.categories
    var find = " "; // find for space in whole string
    var re = new RegExp(find, 'g');
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        e.categories[i] = e.categories[i].replace(re,"-");
    }
    db.companies.save(e);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Do you know how to do with windows cmd?

Comment: You can fire queries direct on the DB console.